# Is this a good way to encrypt passwords in PHP?

Tags: php, encryption, passwords, sha256

```
$encrypted_pass = hash("sha256", $password. "randomSalt");
```

If not, what is a very good method to encrypt PHP passwords (without having to install additional plugins or modules, so I prefer simple methods)?

Thanks.

Comment: No it isn't. Use the [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) functions, which were specifically designed for this purpose.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for [a code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: And traditionally: hashing != encryption

Comment: If you're unclear on cryptography concepts, [start here](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded).